# Converting Date format to other format on Java

Tags: java, date, gwt, format, date-conversion

I have been developing application with GWT on Java. I used calendar tool for my project on this [site](http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo/). When i select any date, give this format (23-Aug-13) to me.

I use this code:

```
final DateField txtBirthofDay = new DateField("Birth of Day", "dob", 190);
txtBirthofDay.setValue(new Date());
```

I want to insert this date to database. So, I have to convert this format (2013-08-23). I converted lots of date format each other before but I didn't convert string type (Aug).

Comment: If you are going to insert the value from Java, you don't need to convert it, simply use the java.util.Date's getTime() method as argument for a new java.sql.Date and JDBC will do the conversion for you. EDIT: If your date is a String, yes, you need to format it. That of (Aug) won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat formats your Date to the given pattern

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Reference these formats [Java Date Format Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

[image: Formats for datetime]

try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date = dt.parse("23-Aug-2013");;

// *** same for the format String below
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    Date date=df.parse("23-Aug-13");
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
    df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String requiredFormatedDate=df.format(date);
    System.out.println(requiredFormatedDate);// 2013-08-23
```