# Change DateFormat in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have data from API, the data is date with format **"2018-07-09"**. How to change the format to **Monday, July 9 , 2018** in android studio?

Comment: *"..in android studio?"* The same way you'd do it in any IDE that handles Android code. Write the code for it. (I.E. the IDE is irrelevant.)

Comment: Please search before asking. In this particular case it shouldn’t be too hard to dig up the first 100 similar questions.

Comment: Similar, for example: [java.util.Date format conversion yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480633/java-util-date-format-conversion-yyyy-mm-dd-to-mm-dd-yyyy).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Date format to other format on Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396543/converting-date-format-to-other-format-on-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse string to object them format it with [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(formatter.format(parser.parse( "2018-07-09"))); // Monday, July 9, 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat fromApi = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy");

try {

    String reformattedStr = myFormat.format(fromApi.parse(inputString));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

See [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL)
            .withLocale(Locale.US);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2018-07-09");
    String formattedDate = date.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

This prints:

> Monday, July 9, 2018

Messages:

- The date string you get from the API, `2018-07-09`, is in ISO 8601 format. `LocalDate` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, parses this format as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter. So don’t go to the trouble of creating one.
- For display to the user use the built-in formats. You get them from the `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedXxxx` methods and may adapt them to the user’s locale as shown in the above code.
- You tagged your question simpledateformat. The `SimpleDateFormat` class is long outdated and notoriously troublesome, so please avoid it. `java.time` is much nicer to work with.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)